# Highcharts - Legend width will not update

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I am trying to update the symbolWidth of my legend for my heatmap dynamically, so that the legend will be the same size as the area of the graph. I cannot seem to get it to redraw the larger legend though. I was trying this:

```
chart: {
            type: 'heatmap',
            events: {
                load: function (event) {
                    this.legend.symbolWidth = this.chartWidth;
                    this.isDirtyLegend = true;
                    this.legend.render();
                }
            }
        },
```

It executes fine, but I don't see the legend size change. I have tried this.redraw() as well. If I look at legend.symbolWidth, the new value is definitely there and updated, but the graph itself does not reflect the update.

I just need a way to have the legend dynamically resize just like the chart does. Here is a jsfiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/4rbtX/

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: it's not supported. The only way is to use some workarounds/hacks (like you have tried).

Try this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/4rbtX/2/

```
            type: 'heatmap',
            events: {
                load: function (event) {
                    this.legend.options.symbolWidth = this.chartWidth;
                    this.legend.destroyItem(this.colorAxis[0]); //remove element from legend
                    this.colorAxis[0].destroy(); // remove xaxis
                    this.series[0].update(); // force to update axis and series
                }
            }
```

Comment: This seems to work. I suppose destroying and updating is what I was missing. Thanks for your help!